# what is the right way to use Google's ClientId with useGoogleLogin Hook?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, react-hooks

I have been trying to add **Google's Oauth2** to my **ReactJs** app

but I get 2 errors which Are probably coming from a syntax error

this is the part of the code where I get the errors

```
import React from 'react'
import { useGoogleLogin } from 'react-use-googlelogin'

const GoogleAuthContext = React.createContext()

export const GoogleAuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const googleAuth = useGoogleLogin({
    clientId: process.env.Google_Client_ID,
  })

  return (
    <GoogleAuthContext.Provider value={googleAuth}>
      {children}
    </GoogleAuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useGoogleAuth = () => React.useContext(GoogleAuthContext);
```

when I do replace **Google_Client_ID** with my own ID I get these errors

> Unexpected token, expected "," (8:25)

and the Second one is

> Unexpected token, expected ":" (8:37)

this is how I use the client ID

```
 const googleAuth = useGoogleLogin({
    clientId:process.env.658977310896-knrl3gka66fldh83dao2rhgbblmd4un9.apps.googleusercontent.com,
  })
```

**THANK YOU for taking the time to Read through my question**

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem

I've used a variable and gave it the value of the client's id instead of using it directly.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useGoogleLogin } from 'react-use-googlelogin'

const GoogleAuthContext = React.createContext()

export const GoogleAuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

//assigning a variable the id value and using the variable instead solved the issue ^_^ 
  const clientId =
  'Google_Client_ID';
  const googleAuth = useGoogleLogin({
    clientId,
  })
```